# C++ plugin to edit image

Tags: python, texturing, add-on, texture-painting

I'm trying to make a c++ and python plugin (something like texture paint tools), but it's too slow because I have to rewrite pixel data (bpy.data.images[0].pixels) completely after every edit. How can this be fastened? Maybe I should send pointer to pixels array to c++? (c++ code is compiled as dll and loaded to python script)

Comment: development questions are [off-topic](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/6/2816) , you have a better chance asking on blender artists' forum in the appropriate section.